# Why is my audio not playing in chrome?

Tags: php, html, audio

I'm trying to run audio alongside html desktop notifications, I get the notification but the sound does not play.

What really gets me is that SOMETIMES it plays the sound, but usually it does not.

Here is my code:

PHP:

```
        $checkTickets2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM techs WHERE needsNotify='1'");
        $tcheckTickets2 = mysqli_num_rows($checkTickets2);

        if($tcheckTickets2 > 0) {
            try { 
                $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password); 
            } catch (PDOException $e) { 
                echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
            }

            $st = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM techs WHERE needsNotify=1'); 
            $st->execute(); 

            $result = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

            foreach($result as $d){ 
                if(strcmp($d['Name'],$_SESSION['Name']) == 0) {
                    echo $d['UniqueID'] . "<br/>"; 
                    $id = $d['UniqueID']; 
                    sendNotify(); //this runs, and works properly
                    sendSound(); //I do not get any sound
                    sleep(3);
                    $st = $db->prepare("UPDATE techs SET needsNotify='0' WHERE UniqueID=$id");
                    $st->execute(); 
                }
            }           
        }
```

Here is my sendSound function:

```
           function sendSound() { ?>
            <audio class="audio" controls autoplay>
              <source src="images/notif.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
             <!-- <embed height="50" width="100" src="images/notif.mp3"> NOT NECESSARY -->
            </audio>
        <? }
```

Comment: You commented your `src` in the audio tag

Comment: Please use the right tags - when sendNotify() works, your problem is not php-related.

Comment: @KhorneHoly It should be using the <source src=> instead.

Comment: @cklm I believe it is PHP related. If I disable the execute command, the sound plays. Its almost like for some reason it doesn't have time to play the audio or something. I don't really know why it would be doing this, thats why I included the php tag.

Comment: @Grumpy what execute do you mean?

Comment: @KhorneHoly The one inside the foreach loop.

Comment: Try to control audio with javascript and use single stream audio for this because is the same audio every time. Check audio api in javascript you need to control two things every time you play it, first stop and second seek to 0 or currentTime=0 to reset the audio context and start from beginning when you play it again and this most happen every time you play it.

Comment: @DurimJusaj I'm not very good with javascript. Can you make an answer and explain the process a bit more please? I would appreciate it a lot. This is the last thing missing from my notifications sytstem.